# Papyrus UML 10.1 freezes in STS 3.4.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, papyrus

after an installation without errors i encounter the following problem in STS 3.4.0
I can create a Papyrus 10.1 project but upon actual creation of the project nothing happens and an empty folder is created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any exceptions in Eclipse Error Log View?